# How do I get the path of the file a Python program was ran with (Windows)?

Tags: python, windows

In Windows, you can drag and drop a file into an application to run the application with the file, which is faster than opening the program then navigating through the file system to find the file, etc.

Now my question is, how do you get the path of the file a Python script was opened with if it's opened in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
import sys
dragged_file_path = sys.argv[1] #sys.argv[0] will always be the path of the running file.
```

So for example if I have a python program that's in D:\User\babushka.py and I dragged D:\juliet.txt to open it, then `sys.argv[0]` would be `'D:\User\babushka.py'` and `sys.argv[1]` would be `'D:\juliet.txt'`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you're asking for. If you're looking for the full path of the executing Python script, try the variable `__file__`:

`print __file__`

If you want its directory:

`print os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want the path of the file that was dropped onto the script. Like with an emulator, for example, you can drag the ROM onto the emulator application and it will launch with the ROM loaded.